# Assigning IDs to dynamically generated HTML tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 PHP framework and Twig. My problem is this:

I have to generate a variable amount of `<select>` elements. Then each select shows a bunch of options from which the user has to choose one. So I want to somehow assign an id attribute to each of these `<select>` elements so I can then get the selected option for each of them.

I've been looking around and trying different things, but nothing has worked so far.

The code I have looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="selectForm">
    {% for i in 1..11 %}
        <select class="select" id="select{{ i }}">
            <option disabled selected> --Select a player -- </option>
                {% for item in items %}
                    <option>...</option>
                {% endfor %}
        </select></br>
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="updateButton">Update</button>
</form>
```

As you can see I've recently tried to use the Twig variable `i`, which iterates the for loop in order to set the id, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: have you looked into using the symfony form .. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html the form component works closely with twig and generates all those for you automatically ..

Comment: The code that you posted generates the `<select>` elements correctly. You can see the result of executing your code here: http://twigfiddle.com/sd3p02

Comment: If you are trying to map `player` options in your template to a Player entity choice field you will need to provide an array of id's as default data to the field. See `.../vendor/symfony/symfony/UPGRADE-2.3.md`, line  173 forward.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Javier was right and apparently my last attempt at assigning the id using the twig loop index was working right, I just couldn't see it because I wasn't selecting the elements properly either and I just didn't think of checking the source code to see if the ids were being assigned properly, so huge thanks to @JavierEguiluz and the rest for the hints!!

Answer (score -2):

you should be concatenating the variable with string instead of printing it

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="selectForm">
    {% for i in 1..11 %}
        {% set sid = "select"~i %}
        <select class="select" id=sid>
            <option disabled selected> --Select a player -- </option>
                {% for item in items %}
                    <option>...</option>
                {% endfor %}
        </select></br>
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="updateButton">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But there is no need to do it. The Twig code is working as expected regarding the `id` attribute. See twigfiddle.com/sd3p02